# Let $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \frac{1}{d}\;$ then prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N F(n)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \frac{1}{d}\;$  then prove that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N  F(n)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

i know the result of this .is we processed using this result

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\right]=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,{\rm d}x$

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{d}{n}$ under the sum? That $d$ is a divisor of $n$ i.e. $d\mid n$?

Comment: @RedundantAunt...sorry i edited its d/n

Comment: You may start from the equality $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}F(n) = \sum_{d=1}^{N} \frac{1}{dN}\bigg\lfloor \frac{N}{d}\bigg\rfloor.$$ The conclusion is then almost immediate from uniform convergence together with the fact that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee..i dont understand .can you give more idea

Comment: Can you show the equality above? It follows from switching the order of double summation. Next, notice that each term on the RHS is bounded by $\frac{1}{d^2}$ and converges to it. Can you prove from this that the limit is exactly $\zeta(2) = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{d^2}$?

Comment: Note that in general : $f(n)=  \sum_{d | n} g(d) \implies \sum_{n \le N} f(n) =  \sum_{d   \le N} g(d) \lfloor N/d \rfloor$

Comment: @SangchulLee...i am trying to understand your idea..any how thanks for your time

Comment: @SangchulLee..i verified that $\zeta(2) = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{d^2}$

Comment: @SangchulLee..but i dont understand the hint you provided ..sorry i am slow learner

Comment: @SangchulLee..can you give me solution ..thanks for your time

Comment: @user1952009..yes..i am confusing .something i am missing

Comment: He gave you almost all the solution $\lfloor N / d \rfloor = N/d - \{N/d\}$ where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in [0,1)$ Therefore $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d = 1}^N \frac{1}{d}\lfloor N / d \rfloor = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{d = 1}^N \frac{1}{d}(N/d-\{N/d\})$ $ = \sum_{d= 1}^N \frac{1}{d^2} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^N \frac{1}{d}) $ $= \sum_{d= 1}^N \frac{1}{d^2} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{\ln N}{N})$

Comment: @user1952009..thanks

Comment: @Psuresh This is the Wintner's mean value theorem. See here for the proof http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739414/wintners-mean-value-theorem/1744032#1744032

Answer (score 1):

Just an explanation for comments by Shanchul Lee and user1952009. We consider the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^N F(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{d\mid n}\frac 1 d$$
Fix some $d$. How many times does $1/d$ appear in the summation? It's not hard to see that this number is equal to the number of $n$ divisible by $d$ where $n\le N$, which can be expressed as $\lfloor N/d\rfloor$. So we may rewrite the sum as
$$\sum_{d=1}^N \bigg\lfloor\frac N d\bigg\rfloor\frac 1 d$$ 
Now note that $|\lfloor N/d\rfloor-N/d|\leq1$, so
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac 1 N \sum_{n=1}^N F(n) - \sum_{d=1}^N \frac 1 {d^2}\right|\\
=&\frac 1 N \left|\sum_{d=1}^N \frac 1 d \left(\bigg\lfloor\frac N d\bigg\rfloor-\frac N d\right)\right|\\
\leq& \frac 1 N\sum_{d=1}^N \frac 1 d=\mathcal O (\log N/N).
\end{align}
Here we invoked the well-known fact that $\sum_{k=1}^N 1/k=\mathcal O(\log n)$.
Now let $N\to\infty$, since $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\log N/N=0$, we get
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac 1 N \sum_{n=1}^N F(n)=\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac 1 {d^2}=\frac{\pi^2} 6$$

Answer (score 1):

For future reference observe that

$$F(n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}
= \frac{1}{n} \sigma(n).$$

Now we have

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s)\zeta(s-1).$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{F(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s+1)\zeta(s).$$

Hence               by               the               [Wiener-Ikehara
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem)
we have

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n\le N} F(n)
\sim \frac{1}{N} \frac{N^1}{1} \mathrm{Res}_{s=1} \zeta(s+1)\zeta(s)
= \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$